# adding colorbox class to Jquery autocomplete <a> link

Tags: jquery, class, autocomplete, colorbox

Im trying to open my result with colorbox,

normaly i can add the class='iframeinscription', and this is working fine everywhere on my website, but this is not working for autocomplete.

this is my code :

```
<script>        
    $(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: [
                <? echo $people; ?>
            ],
            minLength: 1
        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var inner_html = '<a **class="iframeinscription"** title="' + item.label + '" href="user.php?id=' + item.id + '"><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img style="width:37px;border:1px solid black" src="' + item.image + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.label + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append(inner_html)
                .appendTo( ul )
        };
    });
</script>
```

When i inspect element on Chrome and look at the

anyone know why?